# How to make secure sqlserver database and storedProcedures in it

Tags: c#, sql-server, security, stored-procedures

I have an application in c#.net with Sqlserver database.I want to secure database and stored procedures in it .Is there any way that stored procedures no to be open with any body who logged in to sql server to see certificate and master key in it  or modify them. please help me

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your question , you can make role and assign each user to these role, and then grant kind of permission to the users such as Execute, following link can help you

[Grant execute permission for a user on all stored procedures in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428406/grant-execute-permission-for-a-user-on-all-stored-procedures-in-database)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/managing-permissions-with-stored-procedures-in-sql-server