# How give permission for exec but not insert update delete

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, permissions

I have a reader user. Is there any way to give that user exec procedures that is not insert update delete? Only select procs..or stop him from running this kind of proc

Comment: Which dbms are you using? In general I wouldn't expect grant execute on a procedure to give any other permissions.

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428406/grant-execute-permission-for-a-user-on-all-stored-procedures-in-database